# Can I use the Id parameter in a MVC 3 controller action as the Id of a complex parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, model-binding

I have a controller action as the below

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public JsonResult Index(ComplexObject customObject)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

This is what ComplexObject looks like

```
public class ComplexObject
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Here is what I have defined in my area registration:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "MyArea_default",
            "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "MyApp.Areas.MyArea.Controllers" }
        );
```

What I am trying to do is access my controller action like

https://mysite.com/MyArea/{value_of_id}

and have my modelbinder for ComplexObject initialize a new ComplexObject with the id that was passed in.

Is this possible? An internet search offered no help at all.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, mvc will bind a route parameter to a complex obejct. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: I have tried it. I get a 404, I was assuming it is because my parameter is not called Id.

In fact the request does not even reach my custom model binder.

Comment: Well, your url doesn't match your route registration. The issue isnt the complex object, it's that your route registration requires you to declare the controller and the action. try calling it like https://mysite.com/MyArea/Home/index/{value_of_id}.

Comment: You are right, that worked. How can I register the route so that my action can be accessed like


https://mysite.com/MyArea/{value_of_id}

Comment: I'll add it to my answer to make it easier to understand... nevermind. Just change the route url parameter from "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}" to "MyArea/{id}".

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.